# How to cut part of MP4 file using FFmpeg without reencoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I have MP4 file. It's duration is 18 minutes 22 seconds. I want to cut part form 7:35 to 14:01 and to save this part as another MP4 file without reencoding. How to do it using FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you try

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -ss 00:07:35 -to 00:14:01 -c copy output.mp4
```